# Modal start and exit animation logic inside a single React component

Tags: reactjs

I have been trying to solve this problem for a very long time. I will be very glad for your help.

I have 3 functional components.

```
export const HomePage = () => {
    const [menu,setMenu]=useState(false)
    return (

        <>
                    <Header menuState={()=>setMenu(!menu)} />
                    {menu&&<Menu/>}
        </>

    )
}



function Header(props){


    return(
        <div className='Header'>
            <div className='button' onClick={()=>props.menuState()}/>
        </div>
    )
}



function Menu(props){

    function animateExit() {
        console.log("I'm trying to call this function from the Header component")
    }

    useEffect(() => {

        function animateStart() {
            console.log('Animation works! :)')
        }

        return()=>{console.log("In this case, the animation will not have time to appear, as the component will be instantly removed")}
    },[]);


    return(
        <div className='Menu'/>
    )

}
```

By clicking the button in the Header component, I am adding a Menu component to the home page. So I open the menu.
For smooth opening, I use an animation function, for example, I'll call it AnimateStart. It's in the "Menu" component in UseEffect .

To exit the menu, press the same button again.
I really want to put AnimateExit in the menu component. So all the logic of a component is inside that component.
For this you need either:

1. How to call this function from header component
2. Catch the removal of the component through the return of useEffect, but the function in the return must work until the removal. I don't know if this is possible.

At the moment, I'm writing exit animation logic in the Header component. It is not comfortable. I want to put all menu animation in Menu .
I hope you understand what I mean.
I would be glad for any advice on how to make a self-sufficient component, and not scatter its code into different blocks.
Thank you!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but is your requirement to have a `menu` that appears and disappears based on a `button` in your `header` and you want the exit animation to work even after the menu is no longer visible?

Comment: @HasanRiza I want to make the menu appear and disappear smoothly. And for convenience, I want to register both of these animations in one component

Answer (score 0):

From what I was able to understand, you are currently facing problems with making the exit animation work because the `Menu` disappears quickly after clicking on the `button` in the `Header` component.

That is because your code mentions it clearly that show the `Menu` component only when `menu` variable is set to `true`. Which means your exit animation will not have time to be processed. The way you could handle this is by using `CSS` classes that have animation effect on them and you can switch between these classes based on the boolean value in your `menu` variable.

Refer to this example: [CSS based animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68622958/how-to-display-or-hide-component-with-transition-animation-in-react-js)
Also: [Visibility with animation](https://itnext.io/animating-visibility-with-css-an-example-of-react-hooks-8b15685cf7f8)

I'd appreciate it if you could accept the answer if it helps your case!